# Jquery Submit Form in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, forms, safari, submit

In HTML:

```
<form id="deleteMessages" name="deleteMessages" action="/deleteInboxMessage" method="post">
    <!--some input elements here-->

    <input type="submit" id="delete" value="delete"/>
</form>
```

I use jquery to submit the form:

```
$('#delete').bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //some logic here
    $('#deleteMessages').submit();
});
```

It works in Firefox, IE, Chrome, Opera but not in Safari (in Windows). What happened in Safari is that it opens a new tab with the same content as the page. What's the problem? Why does Safari open a new tab?

I also tried button instead of submit but same problem.

Comment: i have try your code in safari and its working .

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT submit a form in a submit button click or a form submission event

Use

```
$('#deleteMessages').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //some logic here
  some AJAX here!
});
```

OR

```
$('#deleteMessages').on('submit', function(e){
  //some logic here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem also, and could not find a suitable fix.

Instead, I did this:

First, Change your submit to a button.

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" class="btn loading">
```

Import Jquery Validate, this will ensure any "required" fields get validated before submitting:

`<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>`

Then add this code. It will work with any button that you set `class="btn loading"`

```
$(function(){
        $(".btn.loading").click(function(e)
        {
            var btn = $(this);

            if (btn.closest('form').valid()) {
                btn.html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> Uploading...Please wait').prop("disabled",true);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    btn.closest('form').submit();
                },100);
            }
        });
    });
```

The time out is necessary, otherwise the moment you call .submit() on Safari, everything else is delayed in queue.

Works in Safari, Chrome and Firefox on Mac (Probably on Windows too).

Edit: Also tested and working in IE9 on Windows 7.

Also, don't forget that doing this will remove `$_POST['SubmitButtonName']` from your list of posted variables. So if you're doing checks against the `$_POST['buttonName']` be sure to change your logic or add a hidden field.

Comment: Need to investigate further as to why the timeout is needed but with 5min before go live this worked for me.